# Converting WCF CORS restful service from .Net 4.5 to 3.5 causes preflight request to break

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, rest

I had a WCF service using CORS hosted on a console application that was working fine in .Net 4.5. the application is now required to work in .Net 3.5 and the preflight OPTIONS request is now failing for any POST request

Here is the interface for the services:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
    BiometricCaptureResponse Start(BiometricCaptureRequest biometricRequest);

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "*")]
    void Options();
```

The actual service:

```
    public BiometricCaptureResponse Start(BiometricCaptureRequest biometricRequest)
    {
        //Stuff and things
    }

    public void Options()
    {
        return;
    }
```

The Behaviour for CORS that gets applied to the requests and response

```
    public string clientOrigin;       

    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel, InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        HttpRequestMessageProperty requestProperty = request.Properties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name]
                      as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

        if (requestProperty != null && requestProperty.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestProperty.Headers["Origin"]))
        {
            clientOrigin = requestProperty.Headers["Origin"];
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
    {
        HttpResponseMessageProperty httpHeader = reply.Properties["httpResponse"] as HttpResponseMessageProperty;

        if (httpHeader != null)
        {
            httpHeader.ApplyCrossOriginSupport(clientOrigin); 
        }
    }

    public static void ApplyCrossOriginSupport(this HttpResponseMessageProperty message, string origin)
    {
        message.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
        message.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Method", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Access-Control-Allow-Method"]);
        message.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Access-Control-Allow-Headers"]);
    }
```

this all worked fin in 4.5 this is the process that would happen:

1. AfterReceiveRequest()
2. Options() service hit
3. BeforeSendReply()
4. AfterReceiveRequest()
5. Start()
6. BeforeSendReply()

Now in 3.5 the Ooptions Service will not get hit which will cause the whole request to fail, Is there anything I am missing to get this working for 3.5?

The Error I am getting from the console of Chrome is:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8502/testservice.svc/rest/Start net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

could this have anything to do with the WebInvoke attribute? It's MSDN page describes it as a 4.5/3.5 Client tech while I am only using .Net 3.5.

UPDATE:
Changing the following atrribute of the options service to use all methods

```
    [WebInvoke(Method = "OPTIONS", UriTemplate = "*")]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "*", UriTemplate = "*")]
```

has allowed option requests to hit the service, the application can work functionally like this but this is still not the optimal solution as it is not specific to an OPTIONS request, any reason behind this?

Comment: What is the error your are getting in 3.5?

Comment: @peer Added the error to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m afraid there is a little bug in the .Net 3.5 Version of the WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector.

The Method OPTIONS in combination with a * UriTemplate is not recognized by the selector.

As a workaround you could replace the default WebHttpBehavior with a custom version.

```
public class CorsWebHttpDispatchOperationSelector : WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector
{

    private WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector target;
    private ServiceEndpoint endpoint;

    OperationDescription optionOperation;

    public CorsWebHttpDispatchOperationSelector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector target)
    {
        this.target = target;
        this.endpoint = endpoint;

        foreach (var item in this.endpoint.Contract.Operations) {
            var webInvoke = item.Behaviors.OfType<WebInvokeAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (webInvoke != null && webInvoke.Method.Equals("options",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) && webInvoke.UriTemplate == "*") {
                optionOperation = item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    #region IDispatchOperationSelector Members

    protected override string SelectOperation(ref Message message, out bool uriMatched)
    {
        var result = target.SelectOperation(ref message);

        var matched = message.Properties["UriMatched"] as bool?;
        message.Properties.Remove("UriMatched");
        message.Properties.Remove("HttpOperationName");
        uriMatched = matched.HasValue && matched.Value;

        var httpRequest = message.Properties["httpRequest"] as HttpRequestMessageProperty;

        var cond = string.IsNullOrEmpty(result) && 
                        httpRequest != null && 
                        httpRequest.Method.Equals("options",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        if (cond && optionOperation != null) {
            result = optionOperation.Name;
            uriMatched = true;
        }

        return result;
    }
    #endregion
}

public class CorsWebHttpBehavior : WebHttpBehavior {
    protected override WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector GetOperationSelector(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
    {
        return new CorsWebHttpDispatchOperationSelector(endpoint, base.GetOperationSelector(endpoint));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is much nicer then using * to catch all, how do you know this is a bug in .Net 3.5?

Comment: @RichardMc well it could be a bug or simply not supported. The code of the WebHttpDispatchOperationSelector differs a Little from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0. When you put a breakpoint on my override of the SelectOperation Method you will see that the target.SelectOperation(ref message) gives you a valid result when built against 4.5 end is empty when built against 3.5